# How do I implement removeMouseListener from a JFrame after I close it?

Tags: java, swing, listener

So I have a class that extends JFrame and implements a mouselistener that looks something like this :

```
public class CollageGallery extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
            :
            :     //stuff

   CollageGallery(){
            :
            : 
       addMouseListener(this)
   }
}
```

I need the mouse listener to go back to focus onto the previously created JFrame and not this one.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `requestFocusInWindow` for the frame you want to become focused...

Comment: so do  you have mean you have  two JFrame  and your want to go back to the previous one.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)  (In this case, the answer has a perfect substitute - a modal `JDialog`..)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean *focus* in the same way as used by the *Java AWT / Swing Documentation*, you would simply call `requestFocusInWindow()` or `requestFocus()` on the component that you want to have focused.

By the way, extending `JFrame` is not recommended. Are you really creating a new class of UI components, or is your intention to merely use `JFrame` in order to display your stuff? If the latter is the case, extension is the wrong thing.

As MadProgrammer commented, if you want to display a frame temporarily, consider using `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` instead of `JFrame`. `JOptionPane` has some nice `static` methods to which you could pass a `JPanel` in order to get it displayed in a dialog until the user presses a button like *Ok* or *Cancel*.

Comment: I just want to display stuff in a JFrame; I guess now in hindsight I should just create a JFrame inside the class rather than extend it. Also, how should the requestFocusInWindow() be called, especially since I need it only after a window is closed?

Comment: @harshalizee Perhaps consider using a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` instead